# How to compare two tuples in PIG?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig, hdfs

I want to filter the records of data set A whose flight_delay_time is less than some specific values(x).

But I will get the value of x from another pig query which is a tuple in the sense x is a tuple.

But using the following statement is throwing an error:

```
B = FILTER A by flight_delay_time < x;
dump B;
```

The data in file A is in the following way;

ravi,savings,avinash,2,char,33,F,22,44,12,13,33,44,22,11,10,22,26
avinash,current,sandeep,3,char,44,M,33,11,10,12,33,22,39,12,23,19,35
supreeth,savings,prabhash,4,char,55,F,22,12,23,12,44,56,7,88,34,23,68
lavi,current,nirmesh,5,char,33,M,11,10,33,34,56,78,54,23,445,66,77
Venkat,savings,bunny,6,char,11,F,99,12,34,55,33,23,45,66,23,23,28

the value of x = (40) which is stored as a tuple.

the last column in the above data denotes the flight_delay_time.

I am extracting the value of X in the following way.

following is the data stored in C_CONTROL_BATCH.txt

25
35
40
15

I used following code to extract the value of X.

```
control_batch = LOAD 'C_CONTROL_BATCH.txt' AS (start:int);
variable = ORDER control_batch BY start DESC;
X = LIMIT starttime 1;
```

Comment: Is x going to have 1 value? Have you tried FLATTEN(x);

Comment: Yes x is going have only value and i have tried FLATTEN(x) but it did not work any other way to filter those records other than using filter?

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Comment: yeah.....i have updated it in the question now.

Comment: Do check if the relation denoted by x, contains the value i.e, 40, in the relation B. It may happen that the relation B is not able to get the value of x

Comment: Can you post how are you fetching the value of X from another pig query?  Can we have a look over that?

Comment: @CodeReaper I have edited the code just check it out

Comment: @ravitheja - You cannot pass a relation directly into a where condition:

B = FILTER A by flight_delay_time < x; // **INCORRECT** as X in a relation here not a standalone value.

Ill post a solution shortly, stuck in a build deadline ryt now!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

**INPUT**

We have two input files:

1. **airlinesdata.txt** - Having the rawdata
   *ravi,savings,avinash,2,char,33,F,22,44,12,13,33,44,22,11,10,22,26
   avinash,current,sandeep,3,char,44,M,33,11,10,12,33,22,39,12,23,19,35
   supreeth,savings,prabhash,4,char,55,F,22,12,23,12,44,56,7,88,34,23,68
   lavi,current,nirmesh,5,char,33,M,11,10,33,34,56,78,54,23,445,66,77
   Venkat,savings,bunny,6,char,11,F,99,12,34,55,33,23,45,66,23,23,28*
2. **x.txt** - Having data from where we get the values of x -
   *20
   30
   35
   38
   37
   40
   29*

**flight_delay_time column is last column in below relation and of type int.**

**Note - If you don't declare it here the program with thrown an exception that it cant cast from byterarray to int when you filter in the end.**

rawdata = LOAD 'airlinesdata.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (field1:chararray,field2:chararray,field3:chararray,field4:chararray,field5:chararray,field6:chararray,field7:chararray,field8:chararray,field9:chararray,field10:chararray,field11:chararray,field12:chararray,field13:chararray,field14:chararray,field15:chararray,field16:chararray,field17:chararray,flight_delay_time:int);

x_data = LOAD 'x.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (x_val:int);

order_x_data = ORDER x_data BY x_val desc;

max_value = LIMIT order_x_data 1;

**Here we are again casting the value to int for the filter condition to work.**

max_value_casted = FOREACH max_value GENERATE $0 as (maxval:int);

**Finally we can issue the filter query to get the results. 
Note how the maxval is accessed below by using the . operator from the max_value_casted relation.**

output_data = FILTER rawdata BY flight_delay_time  < max_value_casted.maxval;

DUMP output_data;

**OUTOUT - Values smaller than max value of X (40)**

*(ravi,savings,avinash,2,char,33,F,22,44,12,13,33,44,22,11,10,22,26)
(avinash,current,sandeep,3,char,44,M,33,11,10,12,33,22,39,12,23,19,35)
(Venkat,savings,bunny,6,char,11,F,99,12,34,55,33,23,45,66,23,23,28)*

Hope it helps :)